# Hard Drive Caddy won't recognize, Xubuntu 18.04, Lenovo T530

Tags: 18.04

My question is about, my question is how to get my PC to recognize the hard drive bay I bought for it.

I have a hard drive caddy I bought to use with the bay on my PC. Basically I was hoping to use a Hard disk to relieve some space on my SSD. However, it won't recognize the bay at all. When I put the original disk drive in, it recognizes with no problem.

Thanks,
Wes

Comment: if you search the dmesg output for sdb, does it show up?  Do you have any partitions on the disk?  What filesystem?

Comment: Connect the drive, then type `journalctl --since "-10 minutes"` in a terminal.